# I'm making an aside react component that will appear to zoom in when hovered over. How do you arrange for state properties?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I feel like maybe the question is compact. Simply put,

I'm trying out React,

> create-react-app

```
{
  "name": "portfolio_react",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.2",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.3.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-scripts": "^2.1.8",
    "reactstrap": "^8.6.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "description": "This project was bootstrapped with [Create React App](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app).",
  "main": "index.js",
  "devDependencies": {},
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/moderah/8r4ND-n-__P-r-f0-iO.git"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/moderah/8r4ND-n-__P-r-f0-iO/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/moderah/8r4ND-n-__P-r-f0-iO#readme"
}
```

After making components, I put the aside("SideLayer") component before projects and floated it to the right.

```
import React from 'react';
import Header from './header'
import FooterPage from './footer';
import Projects from './ProjectsContainer';
import SideLayer from './SideLayer'
import '../styles/App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div classname="App">
      <Header />
      <SideLayer />
      <Projects />
      <FooterPage />
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

In my SideLayer class component, at the moment, I have properties of state declared, returning my RightAside function I've imported.

```
import React from 'react';
import '../styles/aside.css';
import RightAside from './rightAside';


class SideLayer extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state ={
      mouseOver: false,
      isHoveredOver: this.props.mouseOver,
      isZoomed: this.props.isHoveredOver,
      id: 'asideDiv',
      height: '100px',
      width: '100px'
    }



  }

  render(props){
    return(
      <RightAside data={props} />
    )
  }
}
```

I have a variable carrying props backwards, if that's a thing...

and this is where my problem lies:

```
import React from 'react';


const asideDiv = document.getElementById('aside');


function onMouseHover(props){
  this.setState({
      height: this.props.height,
      width: this.props.width
    })
  console.log(this.state.height);
    return asideDiv.style = {
      height: this.state.height,
      width: this.state.width
    };
}



function RightAside(props){
  return(
    <div id="aside" onMouseOver={onMouseHover}>
    <aside>
        <h1>hello</h1>
        <section>
          <article>
            <p>
              One day some crazy shit happen and then
              boom, the world was crazier.
            </p>
          </article>
        </section>
      </aside>
    </div>
  );
}



export default RightAside;
```

I'm really not sure how I should do this.

What's the proper way to make this work?

Comment: Why not just handle this in css with `:hover`?

Comment: This is just for practice

Comment: ended up using the css ```:hover``` method